# void* in linkedList

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, void

i have a simple linked list that looks like this

```
typedef struct Node { 
    void *data;
    struct Node *next
} Node;

typedef struct Node {
Node *head;
Node *tail;
int size;
} LinkedList
```

And my add_node function looks like this :

```
void add_nth_node(LinkedList *list, int n, void *new_data) {
Node *prev, *curr;
Node *new_node;

if (list == NULL) {
    return;
}

/* n >= list->size inseamna adaugarea unui nou nod la finalul listei. */
if (n > list->size) {
    n = list->size;
} else if (n < 0) {
    return;
}

curr = list->head;
prev = NULL;
while (n > 0) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
    --n;
}

new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
if (new_node == NULL) {
    perror("Not enough memory to add element!");
    exit(-1);
}

new_node->data = new_data;
new_node->next = curr;
if (prev == NULL) {
    /* Adica n == 0. */
    list->head = new_node;
} else {
    prev->next = new_node;
}

if (new_node->next == NULL) {
    list->tail = new_node;
}

list->size++;
```

There is something weird when i try to add nodes to the list.
When i add them like this :

```
int i;    
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     add_nth_node(list, i, &i);
}
```

But when i add elements like this :

```
int i, v[10];
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        v[i] = i;
        add_nth_node(list_1, i, &v[i]);
    }
```

Everything is working as expected. Why is that ?
Why do i have to put elements is a vector first to add them to the list.

Comment: Passing a pointer to a temporary loop variable (`&i`) is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Suggest changing either your struct tag ( `typedef struct`  _Node_  ) or the typedef symbol.  They will potentially mask each other otherwise.

Comment: Because `i` will change, `v[i]` won't change

Comment: You have duplicate `struct Node` definitions. Change `typedef struct Node {...} LinkedList` into `typedef struct LinkedList {...} LinkedList` or just `typedef struct {...} LinkedList` since you are not using any named reference to the struct other than the typedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_nth_node(list, i, &i) // (1)
// and
add_nth_node(list_1, i, &v[i]); // (2)
```

They are not the same but the value of data that you assign for each node is the same in two options.

(1) You make the pointer point to address of `i`.

(2) You make the pointer point to address of `v[i]`.

Use (1) is very bad idea because, in this case all `data` of all nodes point to the same address. So if the `data` of one node changes, the data of all nodes change the value.